# Data Show in logcat but not show in text view

Tags: android, json

Data Are show in the logcat but not show in the text view.. what can i do

This is my Log

```
12-29 11:05:13.908: D/gralloc_goldfish(772): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-29 11:05:24.649: D/dalvikvm(772): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 195K, 9% free 7439K/8135K, paused 35ms, total 38ms
12-29 11:05:26.458: D/dalvikvm(772): GC_CONCURRENT freed 229K, 10% free 7628K/8455K, paused 26ms+99ms, total 185ms
12-29 11:05:27.908: D/Create Response(772): {"message":"Login successfully.","success":1}
12-29 11:05:28.598: I/Choreographer(772): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-29 11:05:29.848: D/Create Response(772): {"3":"jmi.mohsin@gmail.com","2":"myname","1":"msnmsn","0":"8527801400","mobile_number":"8527801400","hint":"myname","email_id":"jmi.mohsin@gmail.com","password":"msnmsn"}
12-29 11:05:29.848: I/JSON parse(772): myname
12-29 11:05:29.878: W/System.err(772): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
12-29 11:05:29.878: W/System.err(772):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)
12-29 11:05:29.878: W/System.err(772):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:835)
12-29 11:05:29.878: W/System.err(772):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
12-29 11:05:29.878: W/System.err(772):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
12-29 11:05:29.878: W/System.err(772):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
12-29 11:05:29.888: W/System.err(772):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
12-29 11:05:29.888: W/System.err(772):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
12-29 11:05:29.888: W/System.err(772):  at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6303)
12-29 11:05:29.888: W/System.err(772):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3547)
12-29 11:05:29.888: W/System.err(772):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
12-29 11:05:29.888: W/System.err(772):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
12-29 11:05:29.898: W/System.err(772):  at com.example.phonebook.Welcome$loginAccess.doInBackground(Welcome.java:93)
12-29 11:05:29.898: W/System.err(772):  at com.example.phonebook.Welcome$loginAccess.doInBackground(Welcome.java:1)
12-29 11:05:29.898: W/System.err(772):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-29 11:05:29.898: W/System.err(772):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-29 11:05:29.898: W/System.err(772):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-29 11:05:29.898: W/System.err(772):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-29 11:05:29.908: W/System.err(772):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-29 11:05:29.908: W/System.err(772):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-29 11:05:29.908: W/System.err(772):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This is my **Welcome Activity**

```
    package com.example.phonebook;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONObject;



    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.StrictMode;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Welcome extends Activity {
    //  private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        TextView jsonParsed1,DataShow,hint_data;

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONParser jobj = new JSONParser();
        private static String url = "http://192.168.1.10/android_connect/login_setup/show_data.php";

        //private static final String about = "about"; 
        //  private static final String TAG_SUCCESS="success";
        //  private static final String hint="hint";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork()
            .penaltyLog().build());
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

            jsonParsed1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.jsonParsed);
            DataShow=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.show_all_data);
            hint_data=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hint_datafor_value);

            String abt = getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile_number");
            //Intent i=getIntent();
            //String abt=i.getStringExtra("mobile_number");
            //System.out.println(abt);
            //jsonParsed1.setText(abt);

            new loginAccess().execute();
        }

    class loginAccess extends AsyncTask {

        TextView jsonParsed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jsonParsed);

        private String Content;
        String OutputData = "";
        JSONObject jsonResponse;



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            String abt = getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile_number");

            List params = new ArrayList();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile_number", abt));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"POST", params);

                Content = json.toString();

                Log.d("Create Response", Content);
     /****************** Start Parse Response JSON Data *************/




                try {

                    /****** Creates a new JSONObject with name/value mappings from the JSON string. ********/
                    jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Content);

                    /******* Fetch node values **********/
                   String hint   = jsonResponse.optString("hint").toString();

                    OutputData += "Node : \n\n     "+ hint +"  ";

                    Log.i("JSON parse", hint);

                 /****************** End Parse Response JSON Data *************/     

                  //  jsonParsed.setText( OutputData );

                 } catch (Exception e) {

                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }


                return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) { 
             //      //JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
            //    
            //      /******* Fetch node values **********/
            //        String hint   = jsonResponse.optString("hint").toString();
            //        
            //        OutputData += "Node : \n\n     "+ hint +"  ";
            //        
            //        Log.i("JSON parse", hint);
            //    
            //     /****************** End Parse Response JSON Data *************/     
            //         
            //        hint_data.setText( OutputData );

               jsonParsed.setText( OutputData );

             }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your async task like this:
doing background method of asynctask runs in NON UI Thread, so we can not modify the ui elements from doInbackgroud so we have to return that result so that result will comes in postExecute method as parameter then we can modify the UI

```
    package com.example.phonebook;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.afbb.animationtest.R;

    public class Welcome extends Activity {
        TextView jsonParsed1,DataShow,hint_data;
        TextView jsonParsed ;
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONParser jobj = new JSONParser();
        private static String url = "http://192.168.1.10/android_connect/login_setup/show_data.php";
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork()
            .penaltyLog().build());
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
            jsonParsed1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.jsonParsed);
            DataShow=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.show_all_data);
            hint_data=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hint_datafor_value);
            jsonParsed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jsonParsed);
            String abt = getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile_number");
            new loginAccess().execute();
        }

    class loginAccess extends AsyncTask<String,Void,JSONObject> {
        private String Content;
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            String abt = getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile_number");
            List params = new ArrayList();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile_number", abt));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"POST", params);
                Content = json.toString();
                Log.d("Create Response", Content);
     /****************** Start Parse Response JSON Data *************/
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Content);
                   String hint   = jsonResponse.optString("hint").toString();
                    return jsonResponse;
                 } catch (Exception e) {

                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            //Parse and update the UI
               jsonParsed.setText( OutputData );
             }
        }
    }



i
```

Comment: how i am showing this data in welcome activity.....??..not show only one data {"3":"jmi.mohsin@gmail.com","2":"myname","1":"msnmsn","0":"8527801400","mobile_number":"8527801400","hint":"myname","email_id":"jmi.mohsin@gmail.com","password":"msnmsn"}

Comment: you are not implemented total my code check carefully, not added generics, and you are not returning any value to postExecuted.

Comment: String hint   = jsonResponse.optString("hint").toString();
String email_id   =jsonResponse.optString("email_id").toString();
OutputData += "Node : \n\n"+ hint +"  ";
 Log.i("JSON parse", hint);
                    return hint;
               } catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
                 }


                return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String resutl) { 
              jsonParsed.setText( resutl );
             }   i have to show the  hint,email_id and etc. what can i change in this activity sir....??

Comment: then parse that result in post execute.

Comment: Sir can you change the activity how do i put all in post execute .... please sir  just for example  you can edit the your answer  when i am set in my activity please sir

Comment: modified in my answer.

Comment: Thaku for this but i didn't mean's Parse and update the UI...??? and in this code Output stay the error

Comment: update the ui means update the text view values as you required if my answer is useful accept and at least one upvote.

Comment: sir i have upload the my JSONParse File .... just like this  String hint   = jsonResponse.optString("hint").toString();
               jsonParsed.setText(  hint );  but the jsonResponse is show me the error ....

Comment: perfectly answer show and thanx you sir and thanx the Stackoverflow to meet you..:)

Answer (score 1):

`jsonParsed.setText( OutputData );`
You just put above line in `onPostExecute` method after  `hint_data.setText( OutputData );` line and you will get the perfect output.
And also delete `jsonParsed.setText( OutputData );` line from `doInBackground` method.

Comment: I change What you said but Data Is not Show Perfect... can you set the activity... Deep Mehta Sir

Comment: Edit The Question just you like said

Comment: Log.i("JSON parse", hint); Just put this line in onPostExecute method before jsonParsed.setText( OutputData ); line and you will get the solution i think. Just check that after put this log in onPostExecute method, you will get the data in logcat or not!!

Comment: After putting this line : Log.i("JSON parse", hint); in onPostExecute method, what you are getting in logcat ?? I think you will get blank string!!

Comment: Yes i will get blank String ...... sir can you edit and change this  in my Question ... please sir

Comment: String hint = jsonResponse.optString("hint").toString();    String email_id =jsonResponse.optString("email_id").toString(); OutputData += "Node : \n\n"+ hint +" "; Log.i("JSON parse", hint); return hint; } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }   return OutputData; }     protected void onPostExecute(String  strOutputData) { 
     Log.i("onPostExecute", strOutputData);
        jsonParsed.setText(strOutputData);
 
 } i have to show the hint,email_id and etc. what can i change in this activity sir....??

Comment: I have already edited your question. Please check it once and try!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove below line from doInBackground method

```
 jsonParsed.setText( OutputData );
```

You can not touch view from outside main thread.